# Using a custom homepage URL in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, php

I'm working with [my Magento storefront](http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/), and I'd like visitors who go directly to my my domain to see my "Products" URL (`/products.html`) instead of the homepage defined in Magento's CMS area (the CMS -> Pages area of the admin panel), which is what visitors see now when they go to my bare domain name.

Instead of displaying the homepage defined in the CMS, I'd like visitors to see a more interactive area of my website. I think that the products search and listing area should be what my visitors see first, so that's what I want to do.

How can I make it so that the `/products.html` page is the first thing visitors see, instead of the CMS-defined homepage?

Comment: you can make 301 redirect to products page :)

Comment: Yes I already tried that.

However I didn't see any results.
I redirected: www.efficienttrade.co.nz/
to 
www.efficienttrade.co.nz/products.html

Know any other solution?

Comment: What results? Does page changed to products.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than redirect couldn't you just retrieve the products on the homepage. I have used this method before...

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page

Comment: Ok excellent - I viewed the page you gave and I used this within my home page cms content area.

{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Answer (score 0):

If /products.html is a category page, I believe the easiest method is to set the Default Web URL to the target path for the desired category page.

1. Simply log into your admin
2. Go to: System->Configuration->Web->Default Pages
3. Set **Default Web URL** to the full **Target Path** of your category.

Target Path for categories is typically catalog/category/view/id/{YOUR_CATEGORY_ID}

(Is it obvious you need to change {YOUR_CATEGORY_ID} to the ID of the desired category?)

You can find this path by going to Admin->Catalog->URL Rewrite Management and searching for your category. Go into that record, and use the value in Target Path.

This will make your home page the category page.

Note: You can do this for any product as well by putting in the Target Path of the Product!